# Different padding in ios and android

Tags: android, ios, css, padding

I have this code:

```css
.icon {
 float: left;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding-left: 14px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}

.button {
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: $mfc-white;
 height: 35px;
 outline: 0;
 text-align: left;
 width: 146px;
}
```

The same `padding-left` is different in ios and android.

Chrome Android:
[image: Chrome Android:]

Safari iPhone/iPad:
[image: Safari iPhone/iPad]

I read other post and the problem persists. Any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle. so that we can give a look to other css for text and button too.

Comment: @KiranKumarDash there you go

Comment: I appreciate but adding a fiddle with html and css will really help more in solving the problem. Please create a fiddle : jsfiddle.net/

or add html code to your code snippet. thanks @AlvaroGlez

Comment: @KiranKumarDash I can't. I use AngularJS with test's file and icons from external files. thanks for your comments